# Simple javascript reload not working

Tags: javascript, html, reload

[Here](http://jsbin.com/AvoCuka/1/edit) is the Bin. I am trying to make an example of reloading the page by using `location.reload()` in the function `refresh()` and using `onclick='refresh()'` in a button. For some reason the page is not reloading.

The JS function:

```
function refresh() {
    location.reload();
}
```

The HTML button:

```
<button onclick='refresh()'>Try Refreshing!</button>
```

Comment: You cannot access the function. Its out of scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your refresh method is not in the global scope - it's enclosed within your document.ready.

Move it out from document.ready into it's own script tag.

```
<script>
    function refresh() {
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

[The edited bin](http://jsbin.com/iWAJAFi/1/)

Comment: Can't accept for 10 min. Great answer. I am so stupid for not realizing that.

Answer (score 2):

The `refresh()` function isn't in the global scope. In order to make the function globally accessible, you can do this:

```
window.refresh = function() {
    location.reload();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is defined inside the

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
});
```

body, so the scope of the function name is just that body. As a result, you can't reference it from inline `onXXX` attributes.

Either associate it with the element using

```
$("#buttonid").click(refresh);
```

or define the function outside the document ready function.

Answer (score 1):

you can do directly as

```
<button onclick="window.location.reload()">Try refreshing!</button>
```